# Android SDK Platform-tools revision 1 installation failed

Tags: android

I need to install android SDK.. when I click "SDK Manager.exe" and the installation started

the following message appear "Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 1
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 3214554 bytes, got 22935 bytes." how can i solve 
this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like some connection problem. I would just try again...

Comment: Thanks.. I had problem in my connection ..and now I can Install SDK

Comment: Just a hint: you might want to start accepting some answers if you want to get some answers in the future. 0% is a tiny bit low...